# Преобразование строки в INT64

Tags: php, строки, преобразование

Всем доброго времени суток, подкиньте идею как на php можно строку вида XXX0006548 или XXX000XX48 преобразовать в INT64 вместо X может быть любая буква. Так же необходимо из INT64 получить обратно строку. 
Заранее всем спасибо за предоставленные идеи

Comment: Идея. Сделайте модуль на C.

Comment: а средствами php нельзя обойтись?

Comment: приведите хотя бы пару примеров "преобразований", потому что Ваши строки могут быть шестнадцатеричними числами.

Comment: И что значит int64, что с ним дальше должно происходить ? в случае чего можно воспользоватся `pack()` которая сделает int64 для нужной платформы

Comment: с примером возникают трудности. так как пока не знаю как строку преобразовать в int. 
К примеру есть строка АБС000098 и СДЕ000098 их необходимо преобразовать в целое число, но что бы в дальнейшем была возможность это целое число вернуть в АБС000098 или СДЕ000098

Comment: @Mike, с полученным значением не будет дальнейших действий, а в функцию `pack() ` с каким параметром вызывать?  версия php 5,6

Comment: А каков алфавит ? Т.е. какие буквы допустимы ? Вижу уже русские в ход пошли...

Comment: @Mike , Русские и английские буквы в верхнем регистре

Comment: тогда сделать массив где индексом будет элемент этой строки (т.е. буква или цифра) а значением некий ее код, т.е. номер, если 26 английских + 33 русские + 10 цифр = от 0 до 68. после чего идем по строке, берем по букве, получаем код. Текущее число умножаем на 69 прибавляем полученный код и так в цикле. правда встает вопрос в разрядности обычных переменных на вашей платформе.

Comment: я так понимаю получится следующее если строка АБС000098 тогда А = 26, Б = 27, С = 28 и т.д.выходит 26*69 27*69 28*69 в итоге на выходе получится значение 179418631932000098, в таком случае не понятно как будет проходить обратное действие к примеру если строка будет АБС001932 выйдет значение 179418631932001932 и если его переводить опять в строку выйдет АБС00С

Comment: Если уж кодировать то все. и нули и 98 (если они конечно не константа и их нельзя потом дописать). т.е. цифры то же включать в словарь и в общем алгоритм

Comment: А точный подсчет примерно такой: А=36, Б=37, С=38, 0=0 .. 9=9: `((((((36*69)+37)*69+38)*69+0)*69+0)*69...+9)*69+8` т.е. по факту это перевод числа из системы счисления с основанием 69 в десятичную